# Mapping a Map<String, Entity> in hibernate where the String is an attribut of an attribut of the value entity

Tags: java, hibernate, dictionary, annotations

I got a map attribut: Map  working.
Now i want to change the key so instead of EntityA as a whole it's EntityA.name.

How would i go about this? If it's even possible ...

Posting the code i've atm that works.

Parent:

```
@Entity
public class Parent {

    ...

    @MapKey(name="key")
    @MapKeyClass(Key.class)
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "parent", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private Map<Key, Resource> map;
```

Resource:

```
@Entity
public class Resource {

    ...

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "ID_KEY", nullable = false)
    private Key key;
```

Key:

```
@Entity
public class Key {

    ...

    private String name;
```

I'm looking for way to set Key.name as the map key.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why would you want to do that?  If the assumption that Key.name is a unique attribute ever breaks down you will get unexpected results.

Comment: It's unique for sure, unique constraint in database. I want to just use the name as key to avoid doing a query just to get the entity Key from its name (which is the entering param i've in the methode)

Comment: your query could still be based just the name (select * from Resource where key.name = ?) The uniqueness guarantee is off but it is often thus for searches.

Comment: Aye, i just wanted to know if it was possible to do that within entity mapping so it can be "hidden" in the code. ;)